# Combining CSS nth-child functions

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is my DOM. I need to select the middle column three times, skip a node, repeat:

```
+-------------------+  <div class="grid">
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">1</div>
| | 1 | | 2 | | 3 | |    <div class="cell">2</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">3</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">4</div>
| | 4 | | 5 | | 6 | |    <div class="cell">5</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">6</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">7</div>
| | 7 | | 8 | | 9 | |    <div class="cell">8</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">9</div>
| +---------------+ |
| |    AD UNIT    | |    <div class="adUnit"></div>
| +---------------+ |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">11</div>
| | 11| |12 | |13 | |    <div class="cell">12</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">13</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">14</div>
| |14 | |15 | |16 | |    <div class="cell">15</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">16</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">17</div>
| |17 | |18 | |19 | |    <div class="cell">18</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">19</div>
| +---------------+ |
| |    AD UNIT    | |    <div class="adUnit"></div>
| +---------------+ |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">21</div>
| |21 | |22 | |23 | |    <div class="cell">22</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">23</div>
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |    <div class="cell">24</div>
| |24 | |25 | |...| |    <div class="cell">25</div>
| +---------------+ |    <!-- ... -->
+-------------------+  </div>
```

## tldr

I need to select the following sequence [of children nodes]:

```
 2,  5,  8,
12, 15, 18,
22, 25, 28,
32, 35, 38, ...
```

I have achieved this with three separate nth-child functions:

- `.grid .cell:nth-child(10n + 2)` (2, 12, 22, 32, ...)
- `.grid .cell:nth-child(10n + 5)` (5, 15, 25, 35, ...)
- `.grid .cell:nth-child(10n + 8)` (8, 18, 28, 38, ...)

## Question:

Can these three functions possibly be rewritten into a single one?

Comment: Can you use javascript ?

Comment: No. Why use a canon to kill a mosquito?!

Comment: "Can these three functions possibly be rewritten into a single one?" No, because it's not possible to express such a pattern in terms of a single an+b expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out there's no way to use nth-child or nth-of-type to do what you're after as nth-of-type looks to what type of element you're selecting, not the class.

If you can change the type of element for your ad unit you could get away with nth-of-type, e.g:

```
<div class="cell">1</div>
<aside class="adUnit"></aside>
<div class="cell">2</div>
```

If you can make that change then nth-of-type should allow you to target your divs instead of the asides, e.g:

```
.grid > div.cell:nth-of-type(3n+2) { }
```

EDIT: Adjusted selector as per web-tiki's comment.

Comment: I would suggest to use a `span` rather than a `section` tag which has a semantic value. And the selector should be `:nth-of-type(3n+2)` rather than `:nth-of-type(2n+3)` http://jsfiddle.net/ko170tcj/

Comment: @web-tiki ah good catch, I've edited the answer. However section in this case is semantic, as an ad unit could potentially be used anywhere on the site and is self contained.

Comment: It is not specified what OP wants to put in there anyway. But I assumed it had no semantic value as he was using divs hence the `span` suggestion.

Comment: @web-tiki the structure he represents in asides look like image thumbnails, breaking them with a full width block element that's a span isn't very semantic. Come to think of it the most semantic element would be aside which can be used specifically for advertisements or anything that is considered separate from the main page - updated the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

If you add two empty cells just before (or within) the `AdUnit-class` it will work.

**Empty cells**

```
<div class="cell hide"></div>
<div class="cell hide"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cell:nth-child(3n + 2)
```

*Example:*

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.cell {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
.adUnit {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cell:nth-child(3n + 2) {
    background: navy;
    color: white;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
    <div class="cell hide"></div>
    <div class="cell hide"></div>
    <div class="adUnit">AdUnit</div>
    <div class="cell">11</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell">13</div>
    <div class="cell">14</div>
    <div class="cell">15</div>
    <div class="cell">16</div>
    <div class="cell">17</div>
    <div class="cell">18</div>
    <div class="cell">19</div>
    <div class="cell hide"></div>
    <div class="cell hide"></div>
    <div class="adUnit">AdUnit</div>
    <div class="cell">21</div>
    <div class="cell">22</div>
    <div class="cell">23</div>
    <div class="cell">24</div>
    <div class="cell">25</div>
    <div class="cell">26</div>
    <div class="cell">27</div>
    <div class="cell">28</div>
    <div class="cell">29</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that if I shrink the viewport and need to adjust the selectors, I can just use a media query. With your approach, I'd also need to alter the DOM to account for my styling strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .item {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .text {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .pay-me {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    text-align: center;
    clear: left;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
    background: tomato;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<span class="text pay-me">Has Ad</span>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<span class="text pay-me">Has Ad</span>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<span class="text pay-me">Has Ad</span>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<span class="text pay-me">Has Ad</span>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
<div class="text item"></div>
```

You need to **change the element type** for making it odd-man-out and use `nth-of-type` property